# jquery make table row editable on click and post value on press Enter

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-load

HTML

```
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>etc</th><th>tds</th><th>notes</th></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var input = $('<input/>').attr('value',$(this).text());
    var w = $(this).innerWidth();
    input.css('width',w).css('border','0');
    $(this).empty();
    $(this).append(input);
    input.focusout(function(){$(this).parent().text($(this).val());});
    input.focus();
});
```

I have this simple table and I want user to be populate the table.
user should click on td to enter value and after he complete all 4 fields and press ENTER
the row that he had filled is post to server and table reload.

to do so i was thinking to user `$(this).closest('table').load('tbl.php',{VALUES OF THE TD's in that row});`

tbl.php withh then store row to db, and reload table from db echo new table back.

**My Problem**

1. How to select the td's values and send in in .load()
2. How to trigger that event when user press enter key

Thanks a lot

Comment: is there any point in reloading from server the same data user just entered? Just send it to server and respond with some sort of status code or message so you can alert user if there was any server problem

Comment: Have you looked at how the Jeditable plugin works? When you click on the element to edit it, it appends a `<form>` element so that pressing enter triggers its `submit` event.